# How to set Authorization wise view in the Form in CakePHP-3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to set an authorization in the registration of a form using CakePHP 3.0.

Before asking here, i tried below things but no luck in my favor.

Suppose i have role field in the usersTable like 'superuser', 'admin', 'user'.

I want to provide permission superuser to make all the things like create admin and user. and then admin can create admin and user, and user can make user only.

The code i tried in the add function of UsersController.

```
if($this->Auth->user['role'] === 'superuser'){
        $roles = $this->Users->find('list');            
    } elseif ($this->Auth->user['role'] === 'admin') {
        $roles = $this->Users->find('list')->where(['Users.role !==' => 'superuser']);
    } else {
        $roles = $this->Users->find('list')->where(['Users.role' => 'user']);
    }
```

after failing i tried below things in the add.ctp

```
if(!empty($this->request->session()->check('Auth.User.role') === 'superadmin')){
            echo $this->Form->input('role',['options' => ['admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User']]);
        } elseif(!empty($this->request->session()->check('Auth.User.role') === 'admin')){
            echo $this->Form->input('role',['options' => ['user' => 'User', 'icr' => 'ICR', 'routing' => 'Routing']]);
        } else {
            echo $this->Form->input('role', ['options' => ['user' => 'User']]);
        }
```

Could you please suggest on this regard or is there any easiest way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in your double post @ google groups ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/nTURwYME-6o ) you shoudn't blindy combine three things that have nothing in common, that is guaranteed to blow up.

```
if(!empty($this->request->session()->check('Auth.User.role') === 'superadmin')){}
```

should rather be

```
if ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role') === 'superadmin') {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working now. Is there any other easiest way to do so?

Comment: Using a helper as wrapper would do, see https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AuthUserHelper.php and `$this->AuthUser->hasRole(...)` etc